# Getting maximum and minimum values in very complex condition in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe such as:

```
A       B       C
1.11    NaN     1.11
1.15    0.48    0.79
1.05   -0.29    1.26
0.99    2.90    1.13
0.90   -0.03    0.55
0.80    0.29    1.45
0.75    NaN     NaN
0.73    NaN     NaN
0.77    NaN     NaN
0.81    NaN     NaN
0.85    NaN     NaN
```

I want to get 4 values and make a new dataframe.

(AA) If column B > 0 and column C < 1, Get minimum value C among the values that satisfy the condition.

(BB) If column B < 0 and column C < 1, Get minimum value C among the values that satisfy the condition.

(CC) If column B > 0 and column C > 1, Get maximum value C among the values that satisfy the condition.

(DD) If column B < 0 and column C > 1, Get maximum value C among the values that satisfy the condition.

The result I want is like below:

```
AA      BB      CC      DD
0.79    0.55    1.45    1.26
```

I'd show you another example of dataframe:

```
A       B       C
4.56    NaN     1.77
4.15    0.91    1.17
4.20    0.09    1.14
4.41    0.08    1.07
4.67    0.19    0.93
4.85    0.19    0.82
5.45    0.43    0.52
NaN     NaN     NaN
NaN     NaN     NaN
NaN     NaN     NaN
NaN     NaN     NaN
```

And The result I want is like below:

```
AA      BB      CC      DD
0.52    NaN     1.17    NaN
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare values in masks, chain masks with `&` for bitwise AND with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for filter column `C` and get `min` and `max` values, last create `DataFrame` by constructor:

```
m1 = df.B > 0
m2 = df.C < 1
m3 = df.B < 0
m4 = df.C > 1

AA = df.loc[m1 & m2, 'C'].min()
BB = df.loc[m3 & m2, 'C'].min()
CC = df.loc[m1 & m4, 'C'].max()
DD = df.loc[m3 & m4, 'C'].max()

df = pd.DataFrame([[AA, BB, CC, DD]], columns=['AA','BB','CC','DD'])
print (df)
     AA    BB    CC    DD
0  0.79  0.55  1.45  1.26
```

Output for second `DataFrame`:

```
print (df)
     AA  BB    CC  DD
0  0.52 NaN  1.17 NaN
```

Comment: Do you know how to print only row, but do not print column name? Just like : `0  0.52 NaN  1.17 NaN`

Comment: @MonoNeuElogy - Do you think in file? Because pandas columns are always in `DataFrame`